# cx_Oracle executemany() in Python to load paginated API JSON data to Oracle Database

Tags: python, json, oracle, cx-oracle, executemany

tbls = ['tbl1' , 'tbl2', 'tbl3']

```
            for tbl in tbls:
                apidata = []
                offset = 0
                limit = 3000
                
                while True:
                    print("----")
                    baseurl = f'someurl'
                    url = baseurl + tbl + '?sysparm_offset=' + '{}'.format(offset) + '&sysparm_limit=' + '{}'.format(limit)
                    print("Requesting", url)
                    response = requests.get(url, auth=(apiuser, apipwd), headers=headers )
                    data = response.json()
                    json_string = json.dumps(data)
                    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                    try:
                        with cx_Oracle.connect(dbuser, dbpass, dsn, encoding='UTF-8') as connection:
                            cursor = connection.cursor()
                            sql = 'insert into ' + tbl + '(req_data) values (:req_data)'
                            cursor.execute(sql, [json_string]) #works fine with this sql but super slow
                            
                            #cursor.executemany(sql, ((i,) for i in data['result'])) #TypeError: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement
                            #cursor.executemany(sql, df.values.tolist()) #Python value of type dict not supported.
                            connection.commit()
                    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
                        print('CX_Oracle Error occurred:')
                        print(error)
                    if len(data['result']) == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        apidata.extend(data['result'])
                        offset = offset + 3000
                continue
```

I am trying to pull api data, that is in json format and then trying to insert into a json table in Oracle.
My code goes through each tbl from the tbls list and pull paginated api data 3000 rows at a time and loops the api table through until it finishes pulling. Once it finishes pulling, it does the same for remaining 'tbl' in tbls.
This works fine when used cursor.execute but extremely slow(the api tables have >150k rows).

When I try to use executemany, it just doesn't seem to work for me. I know for executemany, I have to provide a list, which I tried with ((i,) for i in data['result']) and also pandas data frame, df.values.tolist().
I am still a Python noob and would really appreciate if you could point out what I am doing wrong here. I went through a lot of articles/examples on executemnay but I am still having difficulty with this.

Sample of apidata
{'result': [{'owner': {'link': 'https://someurl.com/api/now/table/sys_user/39aec4146fedda00f3ab4ecbbb3ee4ec', 'value': '39aec4146fedda00f3ab4ecbbb3ee4ec'}, 'sys_id': '00c67bbbdbbcb2c01e05fb541d96196b', 'sys_updated_by': 'xa0380', 'sys_created_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'document': {'link': 'https://someurl.com/api/now/table/vtb_task/b1b6bb7bdbbcb2c01e05fb541d961923', 'value': 'b1b6bb7bdbbcb2c01e05fb541d961923'}, 'name': '', 'sys_mod_count': '0', 'sys_updated_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'sys_tags': '', 'sys_created_by': 'xa0380', 'table': 'vtb_task'}]}

The length of apidata varies for different tables but since I am inserting it as json in oracle, it doesn't matter.

Oracle json table ddl:
create table tbl1 (
req_data blob check (req_data is json)
);

Oracle version - 19c
CX_Oracle version - 8.3

Thank you in advance. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding with `executemany()` like this:

```
import cx_Oracle as oracledb
import os
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get('HOME')+'/Downloads/instantclient_19_8')

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
pw = os.environ.get('PYTHON_PASSWORD')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

# For the SELECT statement
def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == oracledb.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.LONG_STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if default_type == oracledb.BLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.LONG_BINARY, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

connection.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler


d1 = """{'result': [{'owner': {'link': 'https://someurl.com/api/now/table/sys_user/39aec4146fedda00f3ab4ecbbb3ee4ec', 'value': '39aec4146fedda00f3ab4ecbbb3ee4ec'}, 'sys_id': '00c67bbbdbbcb2c01e05fb541d96196b', 'sys_updated_by': 'xa0380', 'sys_created_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'document': {'link': 'https://someurl.com/api/now/table/vtb_task/b1b6bb7bdbbcb2c01e05fb541d961923', 'value': 'b1b6bb7bdbbcb2c01e05fb541d961923'}, 'name': '', 'sys_mod_count': '0', 'sys_updated_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'sys_tags': '', 'sys_created_by': 'xa0380', 'table': 'vtb_task'}]}"""

d2 = """{'result': [{'owner': {'link': 'https://someurl2.com/api/now/table/sys_user/xyz', 'value': 'xyz'}, 'sys_id': 'xyz', 'sys_updated_by': 'xa0380', 'sys_created_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'document': {'link': 'https://someurl.com/api/now/table/vtb_task/b1b6bb7bdbbcb2c01e05fb541d961923', 'value': 'xyz'}, 'name': '', 'sys_mod_count': '0', 'sys_updated_on': '2017-02-14 22:25:04', 'sys_tags': '', 'sys_created_by': 'xa0380', 'table': 'vtb_task'}]}"""

data = [
    {"req_data": d1},
    {"req_data": d2}
]

sql = 'insert into tbl1 (req_data) values (:req_data)'

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.executemany(sql, data)


with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select * from tbl1")
    r = cursor.fetchall()
    print(r)
```

Or you could change the statement to use a named bind variable, and then construct the data like:

```
data = [
    (d1,),
    (d2,)
]

sql = 'insert into tbl1 (req_data) values (:1)'
```

Other things to speed up your app:

- Avoid connecting so many times. Instead connect outside the `while` loop.
- Try the new major release of cx_Oracle, which has a 'Thin' mode. The update got renamed to 'python-oracledb', see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher Jones for the guidance. Finally, the executemany works for me. However, I am still getting performance issues even with executemany as it is taking the same amount of time as 'execute'. To insert 2500 rows it is taking an average of 40 secs with both approach. On Oracle side, the wait is on network (SQL*Net more data from client). Based on python-oracledb tuning recommendation I worked with SDU, RECV_BUF_SIZE and SEND_BUF_SIZE on Oracle side but I am not seeing any changes on performance. What am I missing  on Python or on Oracle side?

Comment: Add some instrumentation and see exactly what parts of your app are taking time.

Comment: I used opentelemetry to instrument my code and found some interesting facts. To get API response = 25secs, database activity=14secs. API response in postman=28 secs. Since postman also shows similar response time, it seems it is something on API. Even though database activity is lower than API response, 14secs still seems pretty high to insert 2500k. Do you have any recommendations on any where else to look to improve performance on db activity?